# How to get class name on click - Vue Event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

im new with vue :
is there a better way and short cod for this mess down :

```
 <div  class="opencart"  :class="{activex : isOc }"  @click="chk1()" >
 Opencart <small>(soon)</small>
</div>
<div class="woox" :class="{activex : isWo }" @click="chk2()" >
<img src="../../assets/images/wooLogo.png" >
 Woocommerce
</div>
<div class="shopify" :class="{activex : isSo }" @click="chk3()" >
<img src="../../assets/images/shopify.png" width="80"> 
Shopify
</div>
```

```
  data(){
    return{
      isOc: false,
      isWo: false,
      isSo: false,
      platforms:{ selected: null} 
    }
  },
  methods:{
    
    chk1(){
      this.isOc = true
      this.isWo = false
      this.isSo = false
      this.platforms.selected = 'oc';
      console.log(this.platforms.selected);
    },
    chk2(){
     
      this.isOc = false
      this.isWo = true
      this.isSo = false
      this.platforms.selected = 'woo';
      console.log(this.platforms.selected);

    },
    chk3(){
      this.isOc = false
      this.isWo = false
      this.isSo = true
      this.platforms.selected = 'shopify';
      console.log(this.platforms.selected);

    }
```

i am wondering that, is there best way for write that code above in vue in better way.. without using vue3 composition api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need one variable by plaform? Why don't you use only one which could be either `""` (no platform selected), `"oc"`, `"woo"` or `"shopify"`. Also I would use juste one method and provide it with an argument like so:

```html
<div class="opencart" :class="{activex : selectedPlatform === 'oc'}" @click="handleClick('oc')" >
    Opencart <small>(soon)</small>
</div>
<div class="woox" :class="{activex : selectedPlatform === 'woo'}" @click="handleClick('woo')" >
    <img src="../../assets/images/wooLogo.png" >
    Woocommerce
</div>
<div class="shopify" :class="{activex : selectedPlatform === 'shopify'}" @click="handleClick('shopify')" >
    <img src="../../assets/images/shopify.png" width="80"> 
    Shopify
</div>
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      selectedPlatform: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(selectedPlatform) {
      this.selectedPlatform = selectedPlatform;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Gaetan, i was thinking that vue only accept boolean to handle classes :) ,